# How to import file list and its attributes, from a folder to excel using windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, powershell

I'm using windows 7 and have a folder containing a couple of hundreds of images. Some of the image has lower values of Width and Height in pixels. I'm looking for images which have a small multiple product of this two fields. There isn't a field that sums this up in the fields list.

[image: Image file list with width and height columns]

I would like to trace down those files by exporting the file list and the width and height attributes to excel spreadsheet.

Is there and straight forword way doing so? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: Why not sort the list on width or height?

Comment: Because I want to sort it by the product of this two columns and there isn't one on the list of optional fields to display. Hence, there's an option that some images will have a small number of pixels in their width field but large number of pixels in the height field and vica versa.  I'll modify my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah. Never mind. See my answer.

Comment: Answer updated to calculate area and sort results.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following PowerShell script and then open `sorted.csv` with Excel, and perform further manipulation as required.

**test.ps1:**

```
$image = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
echo ("Name,Width,Height,Area") > test.csv
dir *.png | foreach {
  $fname =$_.FullName
  $image.LoadFile($fname)
  $area=$image.Width*$image.Height
  echo ('"'+$fname+'",'+$image.Width+","+$image.Height+","+$area)
} >> test.csv
# sort the csv by area (ascending)
Import-Csv test.csv | sort Area | Export-Csv -Path sorted.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Notes:

- Uses the [Wia.ImageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630506(VS.85).aspx) Com object.
- `test.csv` contains unsorted output
- `sorted.csv` contains output sorted (ascending) by "Area" (`Width` * `Height`)

**Example output:**

```
PS F:\test> dir *.png


    Directory: F:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       01/09/2015     11:45          27156 1.png
-a----       01/09/2015     11:46          17900 2.png
-a----       21/05/2015     14:40         114304 3.png
-a----       15/04/2015     12:56         429394 4.png


PS F:\test> .\test.ps1
PS F:\test> type test.csv
Name,Width,Height,Area
"F:\test\1.png",869,532,462308
"F:\test\2.png",870,344,299280
"F:\test\3.png",328,328,107584
"F:\test\4.png",546,494,269724
PS F:\test> type sorted.csv
"Name","Width","Height","Area"
"F:\test\3.png","328","328","107584"
"F:\test\4.png","546","494","269724"
"F:\test\2.png","870","344","299280"
"F:\test\1.png","869","532","462308"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- Windows PowerShell Blog: [Image Manipulation in PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/03/30/image-manipulation-in-powershell/)